# Closing sub-menus in shopify

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify, submenu

I am trying to create a store on shopify, thought it was simple but isn't so! Now the problem is I have a home page with navigation menus on the left which has sub-menus in it. Whenever, I go to the home page or refresh the page, all sub-menus are opened. I would like to have them all collapsed. Any idea how?

Comment: Have you checked your theme options for setting on the left menu?

Comment: Hi Yes, I did try few settings but it didnt work. I guess there was some issue in the theme itself.  Finally I decided to change my theme and it worked :)